# How to create an object of class defined inside namespace in c++

Tags: c++

```
namespace t {
    class A {};
}
```

How can create an object of class `A`?

**EDIT :**

```
namespace beta {
  class TESSDLL_API TessBaseAPI 
  { 
     public: 
           TessBaseAPI(); 
           virtual ~TessBaseAPI(); 
  }
}
```

This is the class defined inside `beta`  namespace . Now how do i call the constructor? is

```
tess = new beta::TessBaseAPI();
```

correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
namespace t
{
    A a;
}
```

or

```
t::A a;
```

In the first case `a` lives inside namespace `t` (in fact its full name is `::t::a`).
In the second case `a` is global.

(note: your `class A{}` is missing a `;` after `}`)

Answer (score 5):

As you would normally do. The only difference is that `A` is inside the namespace `t`. So you can :

use the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) every time you want to use `A` :

```
t::A a;
```

use the `using directive`

```
using namespace t; 
A a;
```

or, as Luc Danton pointed out use the `using declaration`

```
using t::A;
A a;
```

**following your edit :**

Assuming that your class declaration is ending with a `;` as in

```
namespace beta {
  class TESSDLL_API TessBaseAPI 
  { 
     public: 
           TessBaseAPI(); 
           virtual ~TessBaseAPI(); 
  };
}
```

Then the correct way to call the constructor is :

```
beta::TessBaseAPI * tess = beta::TessBaseAPI();
```

or

```
beta::TessBaseAPI tess;
```

Comment: `using t::A;` is called a using declaration while `using namespace t;` is a using *directive*.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace t
{
    class A {} a;
    A another_a;
}
```

Now use `t::a` or `t::another_a`.

If you want to make another object:

```
t::A another_a_out_of_namespace_scope;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a semicolon after the declaration of the class, and use:

```
t::A my_object;
```

muntoo's answer allows you to create a single instance of the class and is also correct.

Comment: class TESSDLL_API TessBaseAPI {
 public:
  TessBaseAPI();
  virtual ~TessBaseAPI();
}  this is the class defined inside beta namespace . Now how do i call the constructor?   is tess = new beta::TessBaseAPI(); correct?

Answer (score 0):

For an object named `x`;

```
t::A x;
```